# get object key ending in highest number but not numerical

Tags: php, regex, object

I have an stdclass object like this:

```
  {
    "type": "photo",
    "photo": {
      "id": id,
      "album_id": album_id,
      "owner_id": owner_id,
      "photo_75": "https://example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_130": "https://example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_604": "https://example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_807": "https://example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_1280": "https://example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_2560": "https://example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "width": 2560,
      "height": 1440,
      "text": "",
      "date": 1517775329,
      "access_key": "key"
    }
```

The more complete look is on this pic:[image]

I have my code structure like this:

```
foreach ( $response->posts as $key => $element ) {
    if ( isset ($element->attachments) ) {
       foreach ( $element->attachments as $key_att => $attachment ) {
            if ( $attachment->type == 'photo' ) {
                //get the value of the photo with the maximum resolution
            }
       }
    }
}
```

How do I get only the value of `photo_2560` in this case, pointing it to the `photo_` ending with the maximum numeric value? `max` only works with completely numeric keys... Perhaps would need a regex, but I'm weak at that. Thanks for the help.

P. S. I asked about an array and not an object initially, so the answers given are valid, I made a mistake myself. The initial name of the question was `get array key ending in highest number but not numerical`. I then edited it to reflect my specific issue. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would do using the little known `preg_grep` function:

```
$array = [
      "photo_75"=> "https=>//example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_130"=> "https=>//example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_604"=> "https=>//example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_807"=> "https=>//example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_1280"=> "https=>//example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "photo_2560"=> "https=>//example.com/random_unique_string/random_unique_name.jpg",
      "width"=> 2560,
      "height"=> 1440,
      "text"=> "",
      "date"=> 1517775329,
      "access_key"=> "key"
];

$array = preg_grep('/^photo_\d+$/', array_keys($array));

sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);

print_r(end($array));
```

Output

```
 photo_2560
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/564d080c0e528d396238f14a3cdce275a6b6fb90)

Preg Grep lets you search an array using a regular expression, It's sort of like using array filter and preg_match

```
   $array = array_filter($array, function($item){
        return preg_match('/^photo_\d+$/', $item);
   });
```

But obviously much shorter.  Like array filter it's mostly for use against the values and not the keys, but we can use `array_keys` to get around this. Array Keys returns an array of the keys as the new arrays value `array(0=>'key', ..)` which is exactly what we want.

**UPDATE**

Based on this comment:

> Is there an alternative of array_keys for an object? Because I confused it with an array, unfortunately.

No but you can cast it `(array)$obj` to an array if the properties are public.  We can demonstrate this easily:

```
class foo{

    public $bar = 'hello';
}

print_r(array_keys((array)(new foo)));
```

Output

```
 array(
      0 => 'bar' //which is the key 'bar' or the property named $bar
 )
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1e465e4d2f7bba8f93c43dc3ee9dde9165109c6)

While it's not "ideal" it will work.

**UPDATE1**

> I made edits to my question, please take a look. I don't understand how to apply your example in this case :(

I think it's `$attachment->photo` in your code, it's really hard to tell in the image.  It's whereever the 'stuff' at the very top of you question came from, your example data.

In anycase with your code you would do something like this:

```
foreach ( $response->posts as $key => $element ) {
    if ( isset ($element->attachments) ) {
       foreach ( $element->attachments as $key_att => $attachment ) {
            if ( $attachment->type == 'photo' ) {
                  //new code
                 $array = preg_grep('/^photo_\d+$/', array_keys((array)$attachment->photo));

                 sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
                 $result = end($array);
                 print_r($result);
            }
       } //end foreach
    }
}//end foreach
```

By the way the Regex I am using `^photo_\d+$` is basically this

- `^` match the start of the string
- `photo_` match "photo_" litterally
- `\d+` match one or more digits
- `$` match the end of the string.

Note the `^` can have different meaning depending where it is, for example if its in a character class `[0-9]` (A range of characters `0` to `9` same as `\d`) like this `[^0-9]` it means **NOT** so it makes the character class match everything but what is in it.  Or "negation".  Which is a bit confusing, but that is how it works. In this case it would be anything NOT a digit.

By using the `^` and `$` we are saying that our Regex must match the whole string.  So we can avoid things like `somephoto_79890_aab` which if we **didn't** have the start and end markers our Regex `photo_\d+` would match this part `some[photo_79890]_aab`.

Cheers.

Comment: Is there an alternative of `array_keys` for an object? Because I confused it with an array, unfortunately.

Comment: `array_keys((array)$obj)` - provided the properties are public you can cast it to an array.

Comment: I made edits to my question, please take a look. I don't understand how to apply your example in this case :(

Comment: I believe that `$array` would be `$attachment`  in your loop, so you would just do `array_keys((array)$attachment)` inside there but it's hard to tell by the image, it might be `$attachment->photo` its whatever the stuff at the top of your question came from.

Comment: But I can't apply `sort` on it. If I write `sort((array)$attachment, SORT_NATURAL);`, it then says `Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`

Comment: `$array = preg_grep('/^photo_\d+$/', array_keys((array)$attachment->photo));` then `$array` is what you sort on, which has been turned into  an array.

Comment: Ugh, I completely forgot about declaring that variable `$array` (`$photos` in my case). I'm sorry for the confusion and big thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure no problem, glad I could help.

Comment: @ErikGordon - as you mentioned you don't know Regex very well, I put a brief description of how the one I am using works.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I would be able to write this regex, but wouldn't figure the other part of the solution. I didn't know I could transform an object into an array like that and also I wouldn't think about natural sorting and then selecting the end result. It's very smart, actually.

Comment: Yea I try to avoid writing code, so I write as little as possible that gets the job done... lol ... I have a some wrist issues from years of programing ....  and I  am lazy.  For example where I showed how to do the same thing `preg_grep` does but with `array_filter` and `preg_match` same effect, less code.

Comment: I should mention casting works with most any variable type `(bool)`, `(int)`, `(string)`, `(object)` which gives you stdClass objects from arrays etc...

Answer (score 2):

Regex won't tell you what the highest number is. But, these "photo_N" keys can be sorted using natural order.

> You didn't mention the name of your variable, so I'll just assume `$array` here for the sake of convenience.

Let's first get only the "photo_N" elements from the array:

```
$photos = array_filter(
    $array['photo'],
    function($key) {
        return substr($key, 0, 6) === "photo_";
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

We can now sort the result of that by key, using natural order:

```
ksort($photos, SORT_NATURAL);
```

This should have put the photo with the highest numerical key at the end, so you can get its value using:

```
$photo = end($photos);
```

Comment: The `substr()` refers to the key name, not the number of elements. It checks if the first 6 characters of the key are `photo_`

Comment: @ErikGordon the latter

Comment: Now, provided that I have 2 solutions, which in your opinion is faster?

Comment: Unless you're dealing with thousands of objects in a single script, I very much doubt you will notice any significant difference in speed.

Comment: I just realized that the data is in stdclass object, not array. I confused the terms, so sorry. If you'd be so kind to provide an alternative for stdclass, I'd really appreciate it. For now I'm trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: For this particular way to solve it, change `$array['photo']` to `(array)$array->photo` where `$array` refers to a specific `attachment`